# How do I send a command using swift on iOS app to my arduino?

Tags: swift, xcode, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an app that searches for ble devices that then connects to an arduino that i'm using and i want to be able to send a command to the arduino to turn a motor. I am able to connect to the device successfully and write to the characteristic but when the message gets sent it does not activate my code for the arduino. Any help would be amazing, thank you.
The code from swift is

```
    **func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        print("*******************************************************")

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
            return
        }

        print("Found \(characteristics.count) characteristics!")

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            //looks for the right characteristic

            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(Uuidtx){
                txCharacteristic = characteristic
                print("Tx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
                let string = "unlock"
                let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print(data!)
                peripheral.writeValue(data!, for: characteristic,type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)

            }
        }
    }**

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error discovering services: error")
            return
        }
        print("Message sent")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




}
```

My code for my arduino is

```
#include <Servo.h>


Servo LockMotor;        //initialize a servo object for the connected servo  
String command = "";


void setup() 
{ 
 Serial.begin(9600);
LockMotor.attach(A1); // attach the signal pin of servo to pinA1 of arduino
} 

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
    command = Serial.readString();
    if(command == "unlock")
    {
    LockMotor.writeMicroseconds(1000);
    command = "";
    Serial.println("unlocked");
    } 

    if(command == "lock") 
    {
    LockMotor.writeMicroseconds(2000);
    command = "";
    Serial.println("locked");
    }
  } 
}
```